# How to replicate this write line program 200 times without me copying and pasting it over and oven again changing only one venerable each time ?

Tags: variables, vb.net-2010, procedure

How can i replicate this code changing only one or two variables ?

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim ArrayFS(1, 196, 7) 
    Dim Customer(1, 196) As StreamWriter 
    Dim Profit As Decimal  
    Dim selectedIndex As Integer '
    Dim CustomerLoad(1, 196) As StreamReader

Private Sub BtnSave_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click
Dim Row As Integer = ChkLstRowA.SelectedIndex
        Select Case Row
            Case 0
                Customer(0, 0) = New StreamWriter("G:\theater seats\friday\A1Seat.txt")
                Customer(0, 0).Write(ArrayFS(0, 0, 0) & (" ") & ArrayFS(0, 0, 1) & (", ") & ArrayFS(0, 0, 2) & (", ") & ArrayFS(0, 0, 3) & (", ") & ArrayFS(0, 0, 4) & (", ") & ArrayFS(0, 0, 5) & (", ") & ArrayFS(0, 0, 6) & (", ") & ArrayFS(0, 0, 7))
                MsgBox("Data has been stored.")
                Customer(0, 0).Close()
        End Select
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Which variable do you want to change? This sort of thing can be handled by a simple loop, unless I'm completely misunderstanding you.

Comment: Customer(0, 0) and ArrayFS(0, 0, 0). So like a procedure ( i think that's what this is called ). sorry kinda a noob at this.

Comment: A bit more information is needed...
What are the information stored in the following arrays...
ArrayFs(X, Y,Z) - what are X, Y and Z?
Customer(J,K) - What are J and K?

Comment: Sorry did now you can have a veritable in the array E.g. i don't need to have the following repeating 197 times 
Customer(0, 0) = New StreamWriter("G:\theater seats\friday\A1Seat.txt")
                Customer(0, 0).Write(ArrayFS(0, 0, 0) & (" ") & ArrayFS(0, 0, 1) & (", ") & ArrayFS(0, 0, 2) & (", ") & ArrayFS(0, 0, 3) & (", ") & ArrayFS(0, 0, 4) & (", ") & ArrayFS(0, 0, 5) & (", ") & ArrayFS(0, 0, 6) & (", ") & ArrayFS(0, 0, 7))
                MsgBox("Data has been stored.")
                Customer(0, 0).Close()

Comment: instead i can have 
Customer(0, variable).Write(ArrayFS(0, variable, 0) & (" ") & ArrayFS(0, variable, 1) & (", ") & ArrayFS(0, variable, 2) & (", ") & ArrayFS(0, variable, 3) & (", ") & ArrayFS(0, variable, 4) & (", ") & ArrayFS(0, variable, 5) & (", ") & ArrayFS(0, variable, 6) & (", ") & ArrayFS(0, variable, 7))
                MsgBox("Data has been stored.")
                Customer(0, variable).Close()
o and Z = day
y= place
x = stuff about that place 
lol didn't fit into one comment thing